# which performance metrics to classify model

Tags: model, roc, auc

I wonder between  two performance metrics for classification models: accuracy and area under ROC curve (AUC), which one  is to be preferred in which conditions?  examples appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy is equivalent to AUC for models making binary predictions (although accuracy gives you a more direct interpretation).

In the case you model makes continuous predictions, a ROC curve will allow you to choose a cut-off on which to compute accuracy. In this case, both are complementary, but in the end which metrics to use depends on:

- Are you going to set a cut-off in your predictions anyway, and report only a positive/negative prediction? Then use ROC to determine the cut-off and compute accuracy on it;
- Are you interested to know if the predictions are different in one group than an other, and want to report a probability of the data point being positive? In this case, use AUC.

Comment: @Siga: do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: not really. The answer is quite helpful. But I thought calculating accuracy meant the calculation using confusion matrix. Thank you very much for asking :)

Comment: The accuracy is implicitly computed from the confusion matrix, so does a ROC curve (with multiple confusion matrices, one by cut-off level).

Comment: So  accuracy is better to be used than AUC when one wants to show only positive/negative prediction?

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, as I said accuracy and AUC are equivalent in this case, but accuracy allows a direct interpretation of the misclassification rate.

Comment: @Siga If you think this response was helpful, please upvote it (I did).